# DAX - Filter rows by related table values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

**My data model consists of following tables:**

- DateTable[Date]
- ProductTable[ID, ProductType, DateFrom, DateTo, Flag]
- SCDTable[ID, DateFrom, DateTo ClusterKey]
- ClusterTable[ClusterKey, ClusterName]

**& following relationships**

- DateTable[Date] has inactive relation to ProductTable[DateTo] 1:n. Direction: To ProductTable
- ProductTable[ID] has relation to SCDTable[ID] 1:n, Direction: Both
- SCDTable[ClusterKey] has relation to ClusterTable[ClusterKey] n:1, Direction: To SCDTable

SCDTable contains ProductTable[ID] and corresponding clusters valid in concrete time. Text names of clusters are available in table CluterTable.

Date value is coming from user selection in the report (via slicer).

**I have following measures:**

```
- [AmtProducts] = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ProductTable), ProductTable[Flag] = 1, USERELATIONSHIP( DateTable[Date], ProductTable[DateTo] ) )
- [Temp: LastDaySelectedMonth] = CALCULATE ( MAX ( DateTable[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( DateTable ) )
- [AmtProductsCluster] = CALCULATE( [AmtProducts], [Temp: LastDaySelectedMonth] >= 'SCDTable'[DateFrom], [Temp: LastDaySelectedMonth] < 'SCDTable'[DateTo] )
```

**I have two visuals in my report:**

1. [AmtProducts] based on ProductTable[ProdctType]
2. [AmtProductsCluster] based on ClusterTable[ClusterName]

**Issue is:**

- Results are OK
- When I click in Power BI to any value in visual 1, numbers in visual 2 are filtered accordingly
- When I clcik to any value in visual 2, numbers in visual 1 are not changing

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: probably because in your 2 measure you dont have relationship as in AmtProducts (to DateTable);

Comment: Date table is from database or its created in power bi?

Comment: From DB, but with possibility to do changes

Comment: I can solve it the way that I add '[Temp: LastDaySelectedMonth] >= 'SCDTable'[DateFrom], [Temp: LastDaySelectedMonth] < 'SCDTable'[DateTo]' into [AmtProducts] and then it works, but I'm trying to find better solution as this way I would need to add this condition into every other measure. Plus it would slow down the measure in case that I'm using it without cluster, as it needs to perform additional, unnecessary check.